# Track how much bandwidth/request a user uses?

Tags: php, apache, webserver, bandwidth

Currenty I track each users IP address to get a unique value of a user, and if they register I then get extra data.

But I want to somehow figure out how much data a user is drawing.

Let's say they make a GET request and they have made a request of 5KB, they also download an image which is 200KB.

In total the IP address of the user has downloaded 205KB.

How would I start figuring all this out?

Comment: Do you have the function memory_get_peak_usage() available to use or is it blocked by your host?

Comment: @SpacePhoenix I host it myself, so yeah I do have it.

Comment: @SpacePhoenix But I don't see how it would solve my issue?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please make your question a [mcve]. Also check [ask] to make your post answerable.